# Select previous record if criteria is greater than returned value

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to do a point in time query to return the quantity last recorded in that point in time.

Basically I have a table formatted as such

```
id | other_id | quantity | created
 1     1           5       20
 2     1           2       22
 3     1           1       25
 4     1           8       90
```

If the created queried was 60 I want to return the quantities for the created of 25 and higher
Or from the most recently known quantity since the queried created.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE created >= 60
AND other_id = 1
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Which returns ID:4 but I want the created at 60 which was ID:3
But if the queried created was 25 I want to return 25 and greater

Brain is fried atm and unable to come up with a correct solution

Comment: huh? i don't see any 60.  maybe start with clarifying what you want.

Comment: How can you get a row created `at 60` when there isn't any?

Comment: Query is created >= 60 I want the previous record if the record retrieved is newer and there is an older record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query selects the value before the value you want:

```
SELECT MAX(created)
FROM yourtable
WHERE other_id = 1
AND created <= 60
```

You can then use this as a subquery inside your main query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE created >=
(
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(created), -1)
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE other_id = 1
    AND created <= 60
)
AND other_id = 1
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: If there isn't a previous record IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.created) FROM thetable AS t2 WHERE t2.other_id = t1.other_id AND t2.created <= ? ), ?) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id >= (
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE created <= 60
  AND other_id = 1
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
)
AND other_id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```